# Expansion of $\cos( a \log_e(n+1))$ where $a$ is a constant and $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

Expansion of $$\cos( a  \log_e(n+1))$$ where a is a constant and $n\in \mathbb{N}$

My try-

$$\cos( a  \log_e(n+1))= \cos(a  \log_e n+a\log_e(1+\frac{1}{n}))
=\cos(a\log_e n) \cos(a\log_e(1+\frac{1}{n}))-\sin(a \log_e n)\sin(a\log_e(1+\frac{1}{n}))$$
Now, $$\log_e(1+\frac{1}{n})= \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+\mathcal{o}(\frac{1}{n^3})$$
How to proceed?

Comment: @Thomas Prevost Thanks for the edit. Any idea for the problem?

Comment: Nope, sorry I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

If the expansion in powers of $n $ is meant you can use complex representation of $\cos (x) $ to obtain:

$$\cos (a\log (1+n))=\frac {(1+n)^{ia}+(1+n)^{-ia}}{2}
=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac12\left[\binom {ia}k+\binom{-ia}k  \right]n^k,
$$
where the binomial $\binom zk$ is understood as $\frac {(z)_k}{k!}$ with $(z)_k $ being the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) $z (z-1)\cdots (z-k+1)$.

Comment: So what is the final answer?

Comment: @AnanditaK What are your preferences? I personally like the form with the binomial coefficients.